# I want to go to my filtered source model tree view when I click on Pivot View Data

Tags: xml, pivot, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

When I click on the Pivot View Data , it usually goes to the clicked data's tree view in the Pivot View's model (`pivot.analysis`) .
Instead of this I want to go to my Source Model's Tree View (`account.move.line`).

**Code XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <record id="view_pivot" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">name_pivot</field>
                <field name="model">pivot.analysis</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <pivot string="Analysis">
                        <field name="user_type_id" type="row"/>
                        <field name="balance" type="measure"/>
                    </pivot>
                </field>
            </record>
        <record id="view_analysis_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">analysis_tree</field>
            <field name="model">pivot.analysis</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Analysis">
                    <field name="date"/>
                    <field name="account_id"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="ref"/>
                    <field name="payment_id"/>
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <field name="journal_id"/>
                    <field name="invoice_id"/> 
                    <field name="cost_center_id"/> 
                    <field name="analytic_account_id"/>        
                    <field name="product_id"/>
                    <field name="debit" sum="Total"/>                    
                    <field name="credit" sum="Total"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="menu_action_orchid_entry_analysis" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Entry Analysis</field>
            <field name="res_model">pivot.analysis</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">pivot,tree</field>        
        </record>
```

Thanks in Advance.